# C# How to get all files excluding excluded files from visual studio project

Tags: c#

How to get all files excluding excluded files from visual studio project .

`Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.cs")` is giving me all `'.cs'` files form project folder , but I don't want the files which are excluded from project . Is this possible ?

Comment: If you just want a list, build the project, then you can find them in the output window.

Comment: The files are in the .proj file which is text so you can open the proj file and check if the files are part of the project.